# In pandas, how do you filter a column based on a specific string value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas data frame that looks like:

```py
Col 1
100
$50
200
$250
40
$400
```

How do I go about filtering the '$' and the non '$' values into their own specific columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mask = df.Col.str.startswith("$")

df2["col1"] = df[mask]
df2["col2"] = df[~mask]
```

Comment: Good answer, but it's not efficient to do `str.startswith` twice. Save the boolean array, then call it twice as a variable: `mask = df.Col.str.startswith("$")` Then `~mask`.